# nginx default always returning 404

Tags: nginx

I cannot access my site anymore using the ip address (or domain name). It always `404 Not Found` I use Laravel Forge with Digital Ocean with Ubuntu 14.04.

Here's my **sites-enabled/default nginx** file

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/default/before/*; #That directory is empty

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name default;
    root /home/forge/default/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate;
    # ssl_certificate_key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/default/server/*; #That directory is empty

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/default.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/default/after/*; #That directory is empty
```

**nginx.conf (Without commented lines)**

```
user forge;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        multi_accept on;
}

http {

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

On `sudo service nginx restart` my nginx/error.log only contains:

```
2016/03/24 15:25:07 [notice] 8416#0: signal process started
```

My nginx/default.log is empty.

Any clue of what I could look into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you defined the default server correctly - as per [the Nginx docs](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/#a-default-catch-all-server-block), it should be

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server; 
    server_name _; # This is just an invalid value which will never trigger on a real hostname.
    ...
}
```

Note the `listen 80 default_server;` in particular

Comment: Wow. I was about to reinstall the whole thing. You are a real savior